# FATAL: Module sg not found

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, vmware-server, vmware-tools

When I was installing uptime monitoring agent, I got the error messages:

```
Probing 'sg' devices
FATAL: Module sg not found.
```

But lsmod shows the sg module is loaded:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago)
# uname -r
2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64

# cat /proc/scsi/sg/version
30534   3.5.34 [20061027]

# find /lib/modules -name sg.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi/sg.ko

# lsmod |grep sg
sg                     30186  0

# modprobe -lv|grep sg
# 
# cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep CONFIG_CHR_DEV_SG
CONFIG_CHR_DEV_SG=m
```

Following is the device and file system information:

```
# pvs
  PV         VG             Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg0            lvm2 a-   499.51g 113.51g

# df -hF ext4
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv_root
                       99G  7.9G   86G   9% /
/dev/sda1             485M   36M  425M   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv_opt
                       99G  189M   94G   1% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv_var
                      148G  114G   27G  82% /var


# grep kernel /var/log/messages | grep sg
Jul 21 03:25:04 server810 kernel: imklog 4.6.2, log source = /proc/kmsg started.

# ls /dev/sg*
/dev/sg0  /dev/sg1

# ls -l /dev/sg*
crw-rw---- 1 root cdrom 21, 0 Jul 14 11:10 /dev/sg0
crw-rw---- 1 root disk  21, 1 Jul 14 11:10 /dev/sg1
```

The server is a VMWare guest.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific SCSI device you are trying to use?  SCSI drivers are built in tiers, so it's possible you are hitting an error with a more specific driver for the device you are trying to access.

Are there any /dev/sg* devices?

Are there any sg messages/errors in /var/log/messages or in dmesg?

You could try: 
grep kernel /var/log/messages | grep sg

Comment: <pre>
The server is a VMWare guest. 
# grep kernel /var/log/messages | grep sg
Jul 21 03:25:04 server810 kernel: imklog 4.6.2, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
# ls /dev/sg*
/dev/sg0  /dev/sg1
# ls -l /dev/sg*
crw-rw---- 1 root cdrom 21, 0 Jul 14 11:10 /dev/sg0
crw-rw---- 1 root disk  21, 1 Jul 14 11:10 /dev/sg1
</pre>

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added the information to my original post. The server is a VMWare guest.